# Little problem with indexes

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Suppose I have a diagonal matrix metric, like

$$b_{\mu\nu} = \mbox{diag}(1, -1, -1, -1)$$

namely there are nonzero values only for $\mu = \nu$.

My problem is this (please be quiet to explain me "why" and "how", if you can, if you want): it is clear that if I write for example $b_{22}$ this corresponds to $-1$.

What if I write respectively:

$b^{\mu\nu}$  and  $b_{\mu}^{\nu}$  or  $b^{\mu}_{\nu}$ ??

Thank you so much!

Comment: And: will your answer be valid for every king of metric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b^{\mu \nu}$ is the inverse metric. It is defined through
$$ b_{\mu\nu} b^{\nu \rho} = \delta_\mu^\rho $$
Now in special relativity we encode working with the metric on an index via its placement. An upper index is lowered if we contract it with the metric! We therefore have
$$ b_{\mu \nu} b^{\nu \rho} = b_\mu^\rho = \delta_\mu^\rho $$
i.e. the metric with one index upstairs and one downstairs is the identity matrix.

This is true for any metric.